# How do I go about parsing the contents of a large JSON file with patterns as opposed to having to manually access each entry?

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-3.x

I am attempting to parse [this JSON file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/legacy.json). I need to be able to access and preform a download using the contents of each `hash` entry. How can I do this in Python without having to manually write code to access each and every entry?

Comment: By using a JSON library?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I meant how do I do it automatically without having to write code to parse each and every entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use the [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to parse the data.

You must first load the data from the web and decode it to a Unicode string:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen('https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/legacy.json')
# the default encoding for JSON is UTF-8, but the response can give you
# a different codec
encoding = response.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')

data = json.loads(response.read().decode(encoding))
```

Now you can loop through the data:

```
for name, info in data['objects'].items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, info['hash']))
```

This produces:

```
lang/fr_CA.lang: 6df06576e677d952dc15da3926f4ed822d106354
sounds/random/orb.ogg: e9833a1512b57bcf88ac4fdcc8df4e5a7e9d701d
sounds/mob/villager/yes1.ogg: be73a79fb1ab966887a8b88bed9aa6b3d9173d71
sounds/mob/cat/purreow2.ogg: 08573a1f11058b09c5855122dff47ceb209f771e
sound/mob/spider/say2.ogg: 501b40b97ee55cb7a97943ee620aa05131089fc2
lang/el_GR.lang: 4330e3218548e9f3268d103e5ab71fa2b28d9b20
sound/mob/horse/soft1.ogg: a9a83e3f186b3af56a9844b8d4976c6251ba17eb
sounds/mob/bat/death.ogg: 6df3b2c2b951863fc5200edf3ff3396b105ed897
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the short answer would be the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).